# Problem with sending a GET request using the WiFiEsp library

Tags: esp8266, arduino-mega, wifi

Hello I am trying to make a request using WiFiEsp library but even the examples not working, I have searched a lot but never solved it. most of the solutions are outdated and do not solve anything, I am using Arduino Mega 2560 and ESP8266
the problem as shown in the log is that it's not connected to google.com and I have tried my APIs and I got the same response.

code:

```cpp
/*
 WiFiEsp example: WebClient

 This sketch connects to google website using an ESP8266 module to
 perform a simple web search.

 For more details see: http://yaab-arduino.blogspot.com/p/wifiesp-example-client.html
*/

#include "WiFiEsp.h"

// Emulate Serial1 on pins 6/7 if not present
#ifndef HAVE_HWSERIAL1
#include "SoftwareSerial.h"
SoftwareSerial Serial1(6, 7);  // RX, TX
#endif
char ssid[] = "IOT";          // name
char pass[] = "60606060";     // password
int status = WL_IDLE_STATUS;  // the Wifi radio's status

char server[] = "www.google.com";

// Initialize the Ethernet client object
WiFiEspClient client;

void setup() {
  // initialize serial for debugging
  Serial.begin(115200);
  // initialize serial for ESP module
  Serial1.begin(9600);
  // initialize ESP module
  WiFi.init(&Serial1);

  // check for the presence of the shield
  if (WiFi.status() == WL_NO_SHIELD) {
    Serial.println("WiFi shield not present");
    // don't continue
    while (true)
      ;
  }

  // attempt to connect to WiFi network
  while (status != WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.print("Attempting to connect to WPA SSID: ");
    Serial.println(ssid);
    // Connect to WPA/WPA2 network
    status = WiFi.begin(ssid, pass);
  }

  // you're connected now, so print out the data
  Serial.println("You're connected to the network");

  printWifiStatus();

  Serial.println();
  Serial.println("Starting connection to server...");
  // if you get a connection, report back via serial
  if (client.connectSSL(server, 443)) {
    Serial.println("Connected to server");
    // Make a HTTP request
    client.println("GET / HTTP/1.1");
    delay(100);
    client.println("Host: www.google.com");
    delay(100);

    client.println("Connection: close");
    delay(100);

    client.println();
  }
}

void loop() {
  // if there are incoming bytes available
  // from the server, read them and print them
  while (client.available()) {
    char c = client.read();
    Serial.write(c);
  }

  // if the server's disconnected, stop the client
  if (!client.connected()) {
    Serial.println();
    Serial.println("Disconnecting from server...");
    client.stop();

    // do nothing forevermore
    while (true)
      ;
  }
}


void printWifiStatus() {
  // print the SSID of the network you're attached to
  Serial.print("SSID: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.SSID());

  // print your WiFi shield's IP address
  IPAddress ip = WiFi.localIP();
  Serial.print("IP Address: ");
  Serial.println(ip);

  // print the received signal strength
  long rssi = WiFi.RSSI();
  Serial.print("Signal strength (RSSI):");
  Serial.print(rssi);
  Serial.println(" dBm");
}
```

and this is the log

```
23:21:51.468 -> ----------------------------------------------
23:21:51.468 -> >> AT+CIFSR
23:21:51.533 -> +CIFSR:STAIP,"192.168.1.4"
23:21:51.533 -> +CIFSR:STAMAC,"e8:db:84:df:8b:46"
23:21:51.575 -> 
23:21:51.575 -> OK
23:21:51.575 -> ---------------------------------------------- > 192.168.1.4!h=
23:21:51.575 -> 
23:21:51.575 -> IP Address: 192.168.1.4
23:21:51.575 -> > getCurrentRSSI
23:21:51.575 -> ----------------------------------------------
23:21:51.575 -> >> AT+CWJAP?
23:21:51.607 -> +CWJAP:"IOT","b4:f5:8e:b5:2f:d9",1,-51
23:21:51.653 -> 
23:21:51.653 -> OK
23:21:51.653 -> ---------------------------------------------- > 512
23:21:51.653 -> 
23:21:51.653 -> Signal strength (RSSI):-512 dBm
23:21:51.653 -> 
23:21:51.653 -> Starting connection to server...
23:21:51.653 -> [WiFiEsp] Connecting to www.google.com
23:21:51.653 -> > startClient www.google.com 443
23:21:51.653 -> ----------------------------------------------
23:21:51.653 -> >> AT+CIPSSLSIZE=4096
23:21:51.700 -> 
23:21:51.700 -> OK
23:21:51.700 -> ---------------------------------------------- > 0
23:21:51.700 -> 
23:21:51.700 -> ----------------------------------------------
23:21:51.700 -> >> AT+CIPSTART=3,"SSL","www.google.com",443
23:21:52.018 -> 
23:21:52.018 -> ERROR
23:21:52.018 -> ---------------------------------------------- > 1
23:21:52.018 -> 
23:21:52.018 -> > getClientState 3
23:21:52.018 -> ----------------------------------------------
23:21:52.050 -> >> AT+CIPSTATUS
23:21:52.050 -> 3,CLOSED
23:21:52.050 -> STATUS:4
23:21:52.050 -> 
23:21:52.050 -> OK
23:21:52.050 -> No start tag found: 0
23:21:52.050 -> ---------------------------------------------- > 
23:21:52.092 -> 
23:21:52.092 -> Not connected
23:21:52.092 -> 
23:21:52.092 -> Disconnecting from server...
```

Comment: AT firmware doesn't support TLS 1.3 encryption used by most sites now.. try Jiri Bilek's 'fake' AT firmware https://github.com/JiriBilek/ESP_ATMod Best with my WiFiEspAT library